# Javascript Still submits form when form validation has failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has two 'submit' buttons (Save Draft and Finish) and a Javascript that runs when the Finish button is pressed which checks to make sure all mandatory fields have been completed. The script runs and shows the error if the form validation fails but still ends up submitting the form and I can't work out how to prevent the form from being submitted when validation has failed.

Here's the basics of my form and buttons/script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#editRecord").on("submit", function(e) {
    var buttonClicked = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").val();

    if (buttonClicked === "Continue") {
      if (!validateFinish()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Continue");
      }
    } else if (buttonClicked === "Save Draft") {
      if (!validateSaveDraft()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Save Draft");
      }
    }
  });

  $("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
  });

  function validateFinish(ev) {
    // Add your validation logic for the Finish button here

    var sectionsTouched = $('tbody').has(':checked'),
      inputs = {},
      errorMessage = '';

    if (sectionsTouched.length === 0) {
      errorMessage = 'Please check something first.';
    } else if (sectionsTouched.length > 1) {
      errorMessage = 'Please complete one section only';
    } else {
      sectionsTouched.find('input').each(function(i, e) {
        var me = $(e),
          name = me.attr('name');
        inputs[name] = !!inputs[name] || me.is(':checked');
      });
      $.each(inputs, function(k, v) {
        if (!v) {
          errorMessage = 'Please complete all questions.';
        }
        return v;
      });
    }
    if (errorMessage !== '') {
      $('#error').html(errorMessage);
      ev.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function validateSaveDraft() {
    // Add your validation logic for the Save Draft button here
    return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rate-buttons left py2">
  <input type="submit" name="buttonType" id="saveDraft" value="Save Draft" class="mr1">
  <input type="reset" name="buttonType" value="Reset" class="mx1">
  <input type="submit" name="buttonType" id="submit" value="Continue" class="ml1">
</div>
<div id="error" style="color: red"></div>
```

Hopefully it's something simple that I need to add to the validateFinish function to prevent the form from being submitted if any of the validation tests catch an error with the form.

Comment: did you try to use `ev.preventDefault();`  right after form submit?

Comment: Your validateFinish function takes an event as an argument, but you're not passing one when you call it. I think you need:
if (!validateFinish(e)) {

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I was thinking he must have them inside a <form> , if not then it's my mistake

Comment: in your inputs loop, should you not check `v.value` - `v` should always exist as it's the input

Comment: Thanks @maganthro that was the issue here - had looked at this for hours and completely missed that.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've wasted hours on some really obvious mistakes myself.